# Binary to Decimal Script in Python

Tags: python

I encountered an issue with my Python script that converts binary to decimals. The caveat with this script is that I can only use basic computational functions (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `**`, `%`, `//`), `if/else`, and `for/while` loops.

Shown below is my script:

```
x = int(input("Enter your binary input: "))
z=0

while x != 0:

    for y in range (0,20):
        
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            z += 0*2**y
            x = int(x/10)
            
        
        elif (x % 2 != 0):
            z += 1*2**y
            x = int(x/10)

print(z)
```

While my script works for binaries with short length (e.g., `1101 = 13`), it does not work for long binaries (especially those that have a length of `20`). For example, inputting a binary of `11111010010011000111`, my script returns an output of `1025217` instead of `1025223`.

Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating arithmetic isn't perfect and has a precision limit.

`11111010010011000111 / 10` gives `1.1111010010011e+18`, which when converted to an integer will give you a wrong result and it snowballs from there.

```
>>> int(11111010010011000111 / 10)
1111101001001100032
```

The more binary digits you have, the more "off" your calcuations will be.

**In order to avoid the problem you encountered, use floor division, ie, `x // 10`**.

Or you can skip turning `x` into a number and do the necessary power calculations based off each binary digit and its position.

```
x = input("Enter your binary input: ")[::-1]

n = 0
# this would be more elegant with `enumerate()`, but I assume you can't use it
# same for `sum()` and a comprehension list
for i in range(len(x)):
    n += int(x[i])*2**i
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method

to multiple each of the binary digits with its corresponding value of 2 raised to the power to its index (position from right – 1) and sum them up.

```
binary = input('Binary number: ')
decimal = 0
binary_len = len(binary)

for x in binary:
    binary_len = binary_len - 1
    decimal += pow(2,binary_len) * int(x)
    
print(decimal)
```

input : `11111010010011000111`

output : `1025223`

[More examples](https://pencilprogrammer.com/python-programs/convert-binary-to-decimal/)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `int` to convert any number if you have to write a number converter.
Just use string operations:

```
digits = input("Enter your binary input: ")
number = 0
for digit in digits:
    number = number * 2 + (digit == "1")
print(number)
```

output

```
Enter your binary input: 11111010010011000111
1025223
```